# stmt get_result another way

Tags: php, mysqli, statements

An example of one of my queries...

```
public function db_query_select($query, $params, $param_types){
        $dbc = $this->dbConnect();
        if($stmt = $dbc->prepare($query)){
            //prepared.
            //move the types to the front of the param array
            array_unshift($params, $param_types);
            //call the bind param function with the parameters passed in by reference
            //bind_param only allows by reference.
          call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $this->paramsToRefs($params));
                //binded.
                //attempt to execute the sql statement.
                if ($stmt->execute()){
                            $result = $stmt->get_result();
                            $stmt->close();
                            $dbc->close();
                            return $result;
                }
            }
            //must have failed...
            return NULL;
    }
```

how can I change stmt get_result(); to something that is accepted by shared servers/hosts without the native driver... mysqlnd.

Anyone know? without changing all of my functions that use this database function.

Thanks.

UPDATED:::: Thanks to @your common sense, See Answer.

I believe this is what I was after. Hope it helps anyone that was having the same problem as myself. PDO vs MySQLi, seems simpler... no user call func or anything like that.

*DB HANDLER:*

```
private function dbConnect(){
        $config = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/NTConfig.ini');
        try {
        $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['DB_HOST'].';dbname='.$config['DB_DATABASE'].'', $config['DB_USER'], $config['DB_PASSWORD']);
        $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
        return $dbc;

    }


public function db_query_select($query, $params){
        $dbc = $this->dbConnect();
        if($stmt = $dbc->prepare($query)){
            //prepared.
                //attempt to execute the sql statement.
                if ($stmt->execute($params)){
                    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    print_r($result);
                    //$stmt->close();
                    //$dbc->close();
                    return $result;
                }
            }
            //must have failed...
            return NULL;
    }
```

*Outside the DBHANDLER*

```
$query = "SELECT error_desc FROM nt_errors WHERE error_code = :ERROR_CODE LIMIT 1";
            //array: holds parameters for the query.
            $params = array(
            ':ERROR_CODE' => $code
            );
            $result = $db->db_query_select($query, $params);
            if ($result == NULL){
                $errorText = 'ERROR: Failed to retrieve error';
            }
            else{
                //var_dump($result);
                $errorText = $result['error_desc'];
```

Comment: What does it mean `accepted by servers`? Current result is not accepted? Why do you think so?

Comment: In this example there is no reason to `prepare()`, just call `$result = $dbc->query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: shared servers don't have mysqlnd the native driver installed. I've asked them and it's a requirement for using get_result according to the php documentation

Comment: Just use PDO instead of mysqli and all your problems will disappear in a puff of smoke

Comment: Like I said, you need very simple code. An example can be found here: [a general purpose query function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#query)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, I believe i've converted my code from MySQLi to PDO, correctly... Will fetch() work when i'm returning multiple rows?

Comment: Note that with PDO you can use this function for any query, be it SELECT or UPDATE and also get your data from SELECT in much more formats than in mysqli

Comment: oh you did it wrong. you should return $stmt, just like you did it with mysqli. While fetch should be called later

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ohh okay, Thanks, I'll try that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO is not only much more user friendly than mysqli but also doesn't have any of such a nasty drawbacks. So I strongly suggest to use PDO instead of mysqli.

With DO, the function you're after should be as simple as this

```
function run($sql, $args = NULL)
{
    $pdo = ...;//your means of getting the connection variable
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

After gettin the function's result, you can *chain* a fetch method to its call, fetchColumn() in your case.

Given your code is mostly procedural, let me suggest you a very [simple PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) I wrote. So the full code would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT error_desc FROM nt_errors WHERE error_code = ?";
$errorText = DB::run($sql,[$code])->fetchColumn();
if (!$errorText){
    $errorText = 'ERROR: Failed to retrieve error';
}
```

Here DB class is a better replacement of your dbConnect() function, and run() method is a replacement for `db_query_select()` that actually can be used for any query type, including insert, update or anything.

Comment: Amazing, so much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: As you say, its a very simple method. What are the limitations? What is it unable to handle?

Comment: Well, speaking of run() function, it cannot be used for the multiple execution. For it, you have to use DB::prepare() as it shown in the examples section in the article. As of the DB class, there are no limitations as it supports everything PDO supports.

Comment: Another limitation is one usual for the Singleton pattern. But as long as your code remains procedural, it will do no harm to use it.

Comment: Thanks, got it all converted over to PDO. However, I'm using $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); and I've tried using a try catch both in the run function and in on the line that calls it, but its not catching anything. All i get is uncaught PDO exception. Any ideas? I've looked at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors. MySQLI just returned false on a delete where foreign key constraints were violated but PDO decides to throw the actual error.

Comment: Oh nevermind, i took off ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and now it works like mysqli did! Sorry.

Comment: So you did it the worst way possible. Congrats.

Comment: If your code doesn't catch an exception then you are using namespaces and thus have to address classes properly, like \Exception